# Highchart annotation click event doesn't work

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to add a click event on a Highchart annotation but it doesn't work ..

I tried to set the events property on the annotation object like described here :

https://www.highcharts.com/products/plugin-registry/single/17/Annotations

> events 
>   mouseup, click, dblclick. this in a callback refers to the annotation
>   object.

And I don't find anything about annotation events here : https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/annotations

What I am doing wrong ?

```js
// Data generated from http://www.bikeforums.net/professional-cycling-fans/1113087-2017-tour-de-france-gpx-tcx-files.html
var elevationData = [
    [0.0, 225],
    [0.1, 226],
    [0.2, 228],
    [0.3, 228],
    [0.4, 229],
    [0.5, 229],
    [0.6, 230],
    [0.7, 234],
    [0.8, 235],
    [0.9, 236],
    [1.0, 235],
];

// Now create the chart
Highcharts.chart('container', {

    chart: {
        type: 'area',
        zoomType: 'x',
        panning: true,
        panKey: 'shift',
        scrollablePlotArea: {
            minWidth: 600
        }
    },

    title: {
        text: '2017 Tour de France Stage 8: Dole - Station des Rousses'
    },

    subtitle: {
        text: 'An annotated chart in Highcharts'
    },

    annotations: [{
        labelOptions: {
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.5)',
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            y: 15
        },
        labels: [{
            point: {
                xAxis: 0,
                yAxis: 0,
                x: 0.9,
                y: 235,
            },
            text: 'Arbois',
        }],
        events:{
         click: function(e){alert('test');}
        }
    }],

    xAxis: {
        labels: {
            format: '{value} km'
        },
        minRange: 5,
        title: {
            text: 'Distance'
        }
    },

    yAxis: {
        startOnTick: true,
        endOnTick: false,
        maxPadding: 0.35,
        title: {
            text: null
        },
        labels: {
            format: '{value} m'
        }
    },

    tooltip: {
        headerFormat: 'Distance: {point.x:.1f} km<br>',
        pointFormat: '{point.y} m a. s. l.',
        shared: true
    },

    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },

    series: [{
        data: elevationData,
        lineColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1],
        color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[2],
        fillOpacity: 0.5,
        name: 'Elevation',
        marker: {
            enabled: false
        },
        threshold: null
    }]

});
```

```css
#container {
    max-width: 800px;
    min-width: 380px;
    height: 400px;
    margin: 1em auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/annotations.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px; min-width: 380px"></div>
```

**EDIT :**

I resolved my problem by getting the annotation.group element and assign it a event handler.

```
 for(var annotation in chart.annotations){
   var element = chart.annotations[annotation].group.element;
   element.addEventListener("click",function(e){alert('here I am');});
 }
```

Comment: ok my bad didn't read that, thx.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It not supported, but very simple and quick in implementation. You need to do the **wrap** on the `initLabel` function, and after calling `proceed`, just assign the events defined in your Annotation / label object. Here is the example code with handling click event:

```
(function(H) {
  H.wrap(H.Annotation.prototype, 'initLabel', function(proceed, shapeOptions) {
    proceed.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));

    var label = this.labels[this.labels.length - 1]
    var annotation = label.annotation
    if (label && annotation) {
      label.element.onclick = label.options.events.click || annotation.options.events.click
    }
  })
})(Highcharts)
```

It assigns the event defined in your label object, but if it's undefined, it takes the function definition directly from Annotation object for all labels.

Additionally, you can read more about **Highcharts.wrap()** function here: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts/extending-highcharts

Here is the example of using it: http://jsfiddle.net/ew7ufnjb/

**[EDIT]**

Wrap method is no longer necessary since v7.0. Just delete the wrap method and keep the event definition from general Annotation object.

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/rgm3puL8/

Comment: Thanks 4 the share unfortunately in my highchart looks not work :(

Comment: Could you tell me what exactly doesn't work there? Maybe you could provide me with example, where the problem occurs?

Comment: Thanks 4 the support ill make some other test and let you know more about.

Comment: Hey @daniel_s can you pls update the jsfiddle and show me how to get the x and y position of the annotation click?